# What does the sun.reflect.CallerSensitive annotation mean?

Tags: java, class, security, reflection, classloader

What is implied by `@CallerSensitive` annotation above methods?

For example,the annotation is present in getClassLoader method of Class

```
 @CallerSensitive
    public ClassLoader getClassLoader() {
    //
    }
```

Comment: Start [here](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/176).

Comment: Thanks but it is bit too technical and confusing

Answer (score 53, accepted):

According to the JEP I linked to in the comments (also [here](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/176)),

> A caller-sensitive method varies its behavior according to the class
>   of its immediate caller. It discovers its caller’s class by invoking
>   the `sun.reflect.Reflection.getCallerClass` method.

If you look at the implementation of `Class#forName(String)`

```
@CallerSensitive
public static Class<?> forName(String className)
            throws ClassNotFoundException {
    return forName0(className, true,
                    ClassLoader.getClassLoader(Reflection.getCallerClass()));
}
```

, you notice that it is using [`Reflection.getCallerClass()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/sun/reflect/Reflection.java#Reflection.getCallerClass%28%29). If we look at that method

> Returns the class of the caller of the method calling this method, ignoring frames associated with `java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke()` and its implementation.

```
@CallerSensitive
public static native Class getCallerClass();
```

The problem, it seems, before this JEP, was that if the caller sensitive method was called through reflection instead of directly, there had to be a complex process to identify what the actual calling class was. This was problematic if the method was invoked through reflection. A simpler process was proposed (and introduced) with `@CallerSensitive`.

Basically, the `@CallerSensitive` annotation is used by the JVM

> The JVM will track this annotation and, optionally, enforce the
>   invariant that the `sun.reflect.Reflection.getCallerClass` method can
>   only report the caller of a method when that method is marked with
>   this annotation.

Comment: So I understand that it is useful in reflection to identify the caller class,right?And since JVM is tracking it,JVM wont be able to identify any custom classes having this annotation in their methods.So it is useful for Core libraries?

Comment: @AbhinavKumar Yes, that is my understanding. But I would think custom classes could use it as well. You'd have to try it.

Comment: I'm *very* surprised to see that this sun-internal API leaked into public API of the JDK. Why wasn't isn't a `java.lang.reflect.CallerSensitive` annotation?

Comment: @LukasEder The JEPs seem to only be related to the Open JDK. I don't think I've noticed `@CallerSenstive` in any javadoc that I've gone through, though I have seen references to _caller sensitive_. Maybe other JDKs do it differently. I don't know much about this process.

Comment: @LukasEder I had seen it through decompilation

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis sorry, still didn't understand. Annotation indicates that  method invocation result may be different for different callers. That behavior is achived by the use of Reflection.getCallerClass. So, I don't understand - is it made for a programmer of for a JVM? And if second, how does it help JVM?

Comment: @Boosha It's pretty much only for the JVM. Note the package it belongs to is `sun.reflect.***`. That's not a package available in the JDK. The JEP I linked to in my answer states that it's, among other things, a security improvement and helps better manage callers.

Comment: @AdamSkywalker `Reflection.getCallerClass` takes an argument for the stack depth. Often the caller sensitive method forwards to a common implementation method, in which case one will need to be added to the frame depth. Such refactorings may not necessarily correctly apply the correct correction. APIs may also try to find the caller of a constructor, which is not effective.

Answer (score 1):

From `jdk.internal.reflect.CallerSensitive`

> A method annotated @CallerSensitive is sensitive to its calling class,
>   via Reflection.getCallerClass or via some equivalent.

The equivalent would be `java.lang.StackWalker.getCallerClass` since Java SE 9.

This is effectively the security model of Java versions 1.0 and 1.1, which implemented a sort of pauper's linker checking. It's a coherent approach except for anything related to reflection but is exteremely fragile. The more restrictive Java 2 security model, on the other hand, is magic and doesn't show its workings.

`@CallerSensitive` methods alter behaviour depending upon the class that called them. This is always surprising, but then so is the Java 2 stack-inspection security model. To make matters worse, these method calls are particularly useful for classes that are working on behalf of their caller, so the context is wrong anyway.

The [Secure Coding Guidelines for Java SE](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/seccodeguide-139067.html) covers this area.

- [Guideline 9-8 / ACCESS-8: Safely invoke standard APIs that bypass SecurityManager checks depending on the immediate caller's class loader](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/seccodeguide-139067.html#9-8)
- [Guideline 9-9 / ACCESS-9: Safely invoke standard APIs that perform tasks using the immediate caller's class loader instance](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/seccodeguide-139067.html#9-9)
- [Guideline 9-10 / ACCESS-10: Be aware of standard APIs that perform Java language access checks against the immediate caller](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/seccodeguide-139067.html#9-10)
- [Guideline 9-11 / ACCESS-11: Be aware java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke is ignored for checking the immediate caller](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/seccodeguide-139067.html#9-11)
- [Guideline 9-12 / ACCESS-12: Avoid using caller-sensitive method names in interface classes](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/seccodeguide-139067.html#9-12)

The introduction of modules in Java SE 9 has meant that some of the details have changed.

Additionally if the `@CallerSensitive` method is called with `Method.invoke` some of the stack frames are ignored by `getCallerClass`. Internally the JDK uses a "trampoline" `ClassLoader` to act as a benign dummy caller. `java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle` copies problems of `Method.invoke`. The `AccessController.doPrivileged` methods are also problematic with the consequences of the specification being surprising.

[JEP 176: Mechanical Checking of Caller-Sensitive Methods](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/176) deals with the particular `@CallerSensitive` jdk-internal annotation. The method lists in the Guidelines were generated by a FindBugs plug-in but then manually updated.